# how can i load multiple json file and read files one by one using python

Tags: python, json

I have multiple path (24) of json files, I want to load all the path and open  and read the file and perform the operation on each file

```
def main():
    path = r'C:\Work\metadata'
    m = os.listdir(path)
    for root, dir, files in os.walk(path, topdown = True):
        for f in files:
            x = os.path.join(root, f)
            if x.endswith("_metameta.json"):
                # print(x)
                with open(x, 'r') as fp:
                    data = json.load(fp)
```

I am new in json and in python also help me to find out the way and correct me
thank you

Comment: Looks ok at first glance. Is there a specific problem? If you need help with the "operation" you should explain what it is.